# Solving a non-linear ODE in which one term is a convolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions, convolution

Does anyone have any clue of how to solve the following ODE:

\begin{align}
\frac{F'(t)}{1-F(t)} &= p + (q-w)F(t) + w [F'(u) * e^{-\nu u}](t) \\
\frac{F'(t)}{1-F(t)} &= p + (q-w)F(t) + w \int_0^t F'(t-u) e^{-\nu u} du \\
\frac{F'(t)}{1-F(t)} &= p + (q-w)F(t) + w \int_0^t F'(u) e^{-\nu (t-u)} du
\end{align}

After some algebra, I got the following equivalent ODE:

\begin{align}
\frac{F'(t)}{1-F(t)} &= p + qF(t) - w\nu [F(u) * e^{-\nu u}](t) \\
\frac{F'(t)}{1-F(t)} &= p + qF(t) - w\nu \int_0^t F(t-u) e^{-\nu u} du \\
\frac{F'(t)}{1-F(t)} &= p + qF(t) - w\nu \int_0^t F(u) e^{-\nu (t-u)} du
\end{align}

$F(0)=0$ and $*$ is the convolution operator.

I'm not sure whether it helps, but $F(t)$ is a cdf. So, $0 \le F(t) \le 1$, $lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} F(t) = 1$, and $F'(t) \ge 0$.

Thanks!

--

I tried using Laplace Transform in the second equation:

\begin{align}
-\frac{d}{dt} \log(1-F(t)) &= p + qF(t) - w \nu [F(u) * e^{-\nu u}](t) \\
-\frac{d}{dt} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{[F(t)]^n}{n} &= p + qF(t) - w \nu [F(u) * e^{-\nu u}](t)
\end{align}

So:

\begin{gather}
s \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \mathcal{L}\{F^n(t)\} = \frac{p}{s} + qY(s) - \frac{\nu w Y(s)}{s+\nu} \\
\mathcal{L}\{F(t)\} = Y(s)
\end{gather}

But I'm stuck again.

Comment: $F'(t)/(1-F(t))$ is $-(\log(1-F(t))'$. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks. I had already tried this transformation, but with no success. Now I tried using Laplace Transform.

Comment: Is this what you mean by $[F'(u) * e^{-\nu u}](t) = \int_{0}^{t}F'(t-u)e^{-\nu u} du $?

Comment: Yes. I'll update the question with this information. Thanks, @science.